# Carrierwave & Tire Conflicting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, tire

I have an application that is using both the [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) & [tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire) gems. The problem that I'm running into is when I try to do `rake environment tire:import CLASS=Website FORCE=true --trace` I get:

```
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tire:import (first_time)
** Execute tire:import
[IMPORT] Deleting index 'websites'
[IMPORT] Creating index 'websites' with mapping:
{"website":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"integer"},"title":{"type":"string"}}}}
[IMPORT] Starting import for the 'Website' class
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2/2 | 100% rake aborted!##############################################
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/carrierwave-0.6.0/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:49:in `block in serializable_hash'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/carrierwave-0.6.0/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:48:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/carrierwave-0.6.0/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:48:in `serializable_hash'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/tire-0.4.0/lib/tire/model/search.rb:270:in `to_hash'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/tire-0.4.0/lib/tire/model/search.rb:164:in `to_indexed_json'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/tire-0.4.0/lib/tire/model/search.rb:290:in `to_indexed_json'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/tire-0.4.0/lib/tire/index.rb:306:in `convert_document_to_json'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/tire-0.4.0/lib/tire/index.rb:76:in `block in bulk_store'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `map'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `map'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/tire-0.4.0/lib/tire/index.rb:68:in `bulk_store'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/tire-0.4.0/lib/tire/index.rb:113:in `import'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/tire-0.4.0/lib/tire/tasks.rb:83:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/tire-0.4.0/lib/tire/tasks.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `call'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `block in execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => tire:import
```

There seems to be some kind of conflict between tire and carrier wave. If I remove `mount_uploader :screenshot, ScreenshotUploader` from my Website model then the rake command will succeed. Any ideas as to the cause of this and what a possible solution might be?

Comment: Please update to CarrierWave 0.6.1, this issue was fixed there the other day.

Comment: Do you have a link to the issue # and/or pull request # on github?

Comment: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/pull/681

Comment: Hmm, interesting that the other guy got the +100 bounty.

Comment: The other guy got the bounty because he gave a much more detailed answer w/ the cause of the problem as well as possible workarounds.

Comment: So you're saying a hackish workaround is more useful than us taking the time to fix issues in core CarrierWave? I released a new version JUST because of this issue. Now others will see the other answer below as "The Answer" even though it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying at all. I'm saying that he answered BOTH parts of my question: What is the underlying cause of this conflict and what is a solution? I DO appreciate that you took the time to fix this bug in the gem itself but you didn't explain why the problem was happening in the first place, which is just as important to me. If the problem gets fixed and I have no idea how then I didn't really gain any knowledge from the experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is a conflict with the serializable_hash method which is used by both gems. Tire uses the serializable_hash in their to_hash method which is overwritten by Carrierwave. I hope this helps a bit.

```
# tire-0.4.0/lib/tire/model/search.rb:270
...
def to_hash
  self.serializable_hash
...

# carrierwave-0.6.0/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:46
...
def serializable_hash(options=nil)
...
```

**EDIT**

You could try this (ugly) workaround. Put this into your Website model:

```
def to_hash
  self.serializable_hash_copy
end

def serializable_hash_copy(options = nil)
  options = options.try(:clone) || {}

  options[:except] = Array.wrap(options[:except]).map { |n| n.to_s }
  options[:except] |= Array.wrap(self.class.inheritance_column)

  super(options)
end
```

I hope it works

Comment: This has since been fixed in v0.6.1 of Carrierwave but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!